# how to get the updated data from parent to child as props

Tags: reactjs, react-native

currently, I m trying to pass props data from parent to child and it works fine, but when I m also extracting a field from asyncStorage in the constructor (let's call it brokerName) and then storing it in the props. **This is where the issue arrives**, *the props I m getting in the child element is without brokerName.*

**This is the parent:**

```
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.getBrokername();
        }

        getBrokername = async () => {
            const brokerName = await AsyncStorage.getItem('brokerName');
            this.props = { brokerName };
            console.log('brokerName', brokerName);
        }

        render () {

            return (
                <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                        <VehicleDetails parentProps={this.props} />
                    </View>
                </View>
                );
        }
```

**This is the child:**

```
            export default class VehicleDetails extends React.Component {

                constructor(props) {
                    super(props);
                    console.log('vehicleDetails', this.props); // I m not able to get this.props.brokerName    
                }
            }
```

Any kind of help would be really appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: try         {this.props.brokerName ? <VehicleDetails parentProps={this.props} /> : <h3>Loading</h3>}

Comment: well the loading text remains forever... the page does not gets updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things here.

1. You should never mutate your props, props are read only, what you want to use in those kinds of situations is state [you should read this docs section](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html#a-brief-interlude-props-vs-state)
2. Async actions are side effects. At this moment (react 16) you should not have any side effects in the class constructor or render method.
3. What you're doing doesn't work because your code is async, that means that when the component is created you dispatch a request to fetch some data, but, **by the time your component renders that data is not ready to display**, another problem originates from my first point, as you're mutating the props instead of using state react doesn't know that it needs to re-render and that's the root of your problem.

To fix this:

- Move your async request to `componentDidMount` lifecycle method [check the lifecycle methods here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)
- set state when the request is data is ready
- Inject the state as a prop in your child component

Answer (score 0):

Parent

```
constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state={
              brokerName:null
            }
            this.getBrokername();
        }

        getBrokername = async () => {
            const brokerName = await AsyncStorage.getItem('brokerName');
            this.setState({brokerName:brokerName})
            console.log('brokerName', brokerName);
        }

        render () {

            return (
                <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                        <VehicleDetails brokerName={this.state.brokerName} 
                  />
                    </View>
                </View>
                );
        }
```

Child

```
export default class VehicleDetails extends React.Component {

                constructor(props) {
                    super(props);
                    console.log('vehicleDetails', this.props);
                }
            }
```

you can get parents props in props key ex : `<parent name={`name`}/>` so u can access name using `this.props.name`

Comment: well, I tried this but it doesn't work, broker name is received as null. most probably because it's not right to call setState before the component is mounted i.e: inside a method which is inside constructor since the render is not called yet and what will the setState re-render. please do correct me if I m wrong, I m not that experienced yet :)

Comment: check ur local storage if ur get value from that?

Answer (score 0):

after reading **Diogo Cunha's** answer, **Asif vora's** example and **Akash Salunkhe's** comment above, I came up with this solution and its working fine.
Thanks for all your help.

```
            constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.state={
                    brokerName:null
                }
                console.log('details props', this.props);
            }

            componentDidMount() {
                this.getBrokername();
            }

            getBrokername = async () => {
                const brokerName = await AsyncStorage.getItem('brokerName');
                this.setState({brokerName:brokerName});
                console.log('brokerName', this.state, brokerName);
            }

            render () {

            return (
                <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                        {this.state.brokerName ? <VehicleDetails parentProps={this.props} brokerName={this.state.brokerName} /> : null }
                    </View>
                </View>
            );
        }
```

*Please feel free to give your suggestion for any kind of improvement in the answer.*